# How to print integer numbers of a tuple (2,1,4) without spaces

Tags: python, string, tuples

How to print the **tuple** `(2, 1, 4)` without spaces in Python.
I am getting a extra space before `1` and `4` in the output.
Below is the report:

```
Expected    Obtained    Difference
(2,1,4)    (2, 1, 4)    (2,_1,_4)
```

Comment: `co-ordinate` isn't a Python type. What type is your input: `str`, `tuple`, or something else?

Comment: Please show your current code of printing

Comment: @jpp this co-ordinate is coming after a calculation which is int type

Comment: @CaoMinhVu I will not be able to share the code because it is copy paste restricted code only thing which i can share with you is that this co-ordinate is coming after a calculation which is int type in nature

Comment: @rabikrshaw, So you have a `tuple`, please be clear in future, I've edited the question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringify your value, and then replace the spaces with blanks:

```
val = (2, 1, 4)

print(val)

print(str(val).replace(' ', ''))
```

Output:

```
(2, 1, 4)
(2,1,4)
```

This will work for any length tuple or list.

Comment: Thanks @DatHydroGuy it is working with the code suggested by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> val = (2, 1, 4)
>>> print("({},{},{})".format(*val))
(2,1,4)
```

For "coordinates" in higher dimensions, building the string yourself using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) could be more generalizable:

```
>>> val = (2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9)
>>> print("("+",".join(map(str, val))+")")
(2,1,4,7,8,9)
```

Comment: your(@Christian) suggested code is also working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
val = (2, 1, 4)

print(f'({",".join(map(str, val))})')

(2,1,4)
```

If you do this often, you can create a `MyTuple` object, which always prints in this fashion:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'({",".join(map(str, val))})'

val = (2, 1, 4)
val = MyTuple(val)

print(val)

(2,1,4)
```